# Remove \" from a string

Tags: regex, r

I have problem in removing `\"` from my text.

Below is example of data that I have:

```
Date          Text
15/03/2015    \"My name is Jane. I \" am a girl.
20/03/2015    Hi, \"I am bored\". Are you\"?
```

I would like to get this output (by removing `\"`):

```
Date          Text
15/03/2015    My name is Jane. I am a girl.
20/03/2015    Hi, I am bored. Are you?
```

Below is one of the codes I tried:

```
text <- c(" \"My name is Jane. I \" am a girl.",
          "Hi, \"I am bored\". Are you\"? ")
text <- gsub ("[^[:alum:][:space:]?|.|,]", "", text, perl = TRUE)

cname <- file.path ("~", "Desktop", "Demo", "Corpus")
length(dor(cname))
dir(cname)
a <- Corpus (DirSoure(cname))
test <- DocumentTermMatrix (a)
findFreqTerms(helo)
```

The output I get is:

```
[1]\"My   
[2]name
[3]is
[4]Jane
[5]I
[6]\"
[7]am
[8]a
[9]girl.
[10]Hi,
[11]\"I   
[12]am
[13]bored\".
[14]Are
[15]you\"?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash and the quote. Maybe try this,

```
text <- c(" \"My name is Jane. I \" am a girl.",
          "Hi, \"I am bored\". Are you\"? ")
output <- gsub("\\\"","",text)
output
[1] " My name is Jane. I  am a girl." "Hi, I am bored. Are you? "
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am able to do it, however, when i pass it through the corpus, the \" come back. @Avinash

Answer (score 2):

```
text <- c(" \"My name is Jane. I \" am a girl.",
"Hi, \"I am bored\". Are you\"? ")

step1 = gsub('"','', text, fixed = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am able to do it, however, when i pass it through the corpus, the \" come back. @hanshansen

Comment: what do you mean with "corpus"?